# problem for send data with axios on my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

i have send my data wit axios on array (mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]=splitDay) but i have a error...

```
components: { VueCal },
data() {
    return {
        users:[],
        mois:[],
        assignments:[],
        selectedEvent: {},
        showDialog: false,
        events: [],//recuperer tache ici
        minCellWidth: 400,
        minSplitWidth: 150,
        splitDays:mySplitDays        
    };
},
async mounted() {
    let response = await axios
    .get(`${process.env.***}/users?role=***&active=***`)
    let mySplitDays = response.data
    for (let splitDayIndex in mySplitDays){
        let splitDay= mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]
        splitDay.class = splitDay.lastname
        splitDay.label = splitDay.lastname
        mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]=splitDay
    }
}
```

[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: mySplitDays is not defined"

ReferenceError: mySplitDays is not defined

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js?{"id":"data-v-aae30ed8","hasScoped":true,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Dashboard.vue (app.js:2705), :15:31)

Comment: what is the content of reponse? It looks like response.data might be null. Try calling the API from postman to see if it works

Comment: which answer ?  when i'm still in axios i have all of my data

Comment: try running console.log(response.data) after the axios call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign mySplitDays to data when the component is created. There is no variable called that existing at that point. You should add a default value such as an empty array to splitDays. Empty array is probably the best default value as it has a length property and thus if you use that somewhere in the template it will not cause issues. Then inside the mounted function assign the result from axios to data.

Comment: ok but after "splitDays:[]" where should i put mySplitDays = splitDays?

Comment: You can assign a value to splitDays inside mounted using this.splitDays = mySplitdays